# Expo EAS build crashing on production but working on ExpoGo

Tags: javascript, react-native, crash, expo, eas

I've been trying for days to make this work with no luck
I recently migrated to EAS build, and, although I'm able to build successfully, the app crashes on the splash screen.
I pre-built to run on Xcode, and this is the debug output:

> 2023-01-11 18:06:55.054066-0300 Foodhi[7212:12185149]
> [SceneConfiguration] Info.plist contained no UIScene configuration
> dictionary (looking for configuration named "(no name)") 2023-01-11
> 18:06:55.055026-0300 Foodhi[7212:12185149] [SceneConfiguration]
> Info.plist contained no UIScene configuration dictionary (looking for
> configuration named "(no name)") 2023-01-11 18:06:55.595496-0300
> Foodhi[7212:12185149] [native] Running application main ({
> initialProps =     {
> };
> rootTag = 1; }) 2023-01-11 18:06:55.899161-0300 Foodhi[7212:12185149] [native]   
>  Error
>
> ```
> Error:
> Cannot find module 'metro-hermes-compiler'
> Require
> stack:
> -
> /private/var/folders/wp/tyk971fn42j897jg2pwz6zfr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/4a382403-f572-494b-a681-af200dfe3929/build/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js
> -
> /private/var/folders/wp/tyk971fn42j897jg2pwz6zfr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/4a382403-f572-494b-a681-af200dfe3929/build/node_modules/metro/src/shared/output/bundle.flow.js
> -
> /private/var/folders/wp/tyk971fn42j897jg2pwz6zfr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/4a382403-f572-494b-a681-af200dfe3929/build/node_modules/metro/src/shared/output/bundle.js
> -
> /private/var/folders/wp/tyk971fn42j897jg2pwz6zfr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/4a382403-f572-494b-a681-af200dfe3929/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/build/commands/bundle/buildBundle.js
> -
> /private/var/folders/wp/tyk971fn42j897jg2pwz6zfr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/4a382403-f572-494b-a681-af200dfe3929/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/build/commands/bundle/bundle.js
> -
> /private/var/folders/wp/tyk971fn42j897jg2pwz6zfr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/4a382403-f572-494b-a681-af200dfe3929/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/build/commands/bundle/index.js
> - /private/var/folders/wp/tyk971fn42j897jg2pwz6zfr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/4a382403-f572-494b-a681-af200dfe3929/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/build/commands/index.js
> -
> /private/var/folders/wp/tyk971fn42j897jg2pwz6zfr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/4a382403-f572-494b-a681-af200dfe3929/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/build/index.js
> -
> /private/var/folders/wp/tyk971fn42j897jg2pwz6zfr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/4a382403-f572-494b-a681-af200dfe3929/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/commands/index.js
> -
> /private/var/folders/wp/tyk971fn42j897jg2pwz6zfr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/4a382403-f572-494b-a681-af200dfe3929/build/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js
> -
> /private/var/folders/wp/tyk971fn42j897jg2pwz6zfr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/4a382403-f572-494b-a681-af200dfe3929/build/node_modules/react-native/cli.js
>
>    at Function.Module._resolveFilename
> (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:15)
>     at
> Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:833:27)
>
>    at Module.require
> (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1057:19)
>     at require
> (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
>     at
> getBytecodeVersion
> (/private/var/folders/wp/tyk971fn42j897jg2pwz6zfr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/4a382403-f572-494b-a681-af200dfe3929/build/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:79:10)
>
>    at Server._parseOptions
> (/private/var/folders/wp/tyk971fn42j897jg2pwz6zfr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/4a382403-f572-494b-a681-af200dfe3929/build/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:413:7)
>
>    at Server._processRequest
> (/private/var/folders/wp/tyk971fn42j897jg2pwz6zfr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/4a382403-f572-494b-a681-af200dfe3929/build/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:430:28)
>
>    at processRequest
> (/private/var/folders/wp/tyk971fn42j897jg2pwz6zfr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/4a382403-f572-494b-a681-af200dfe3929/build/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:406:10)
>
>    at call
> (/private/var/folders/wp/tyk971fn42j897jg2pwz6zfr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/4a382403-f572-494b-a681-af200dfe3929/build/node_modules/connect/index.js:239:7)
>     at next
> (/private/var/folders/wp/tyk971fn42j897jg2pwz6zfr0000gn/T/eas-build-local-nodejs/4a382403-f572-494b-a681-af200dfe3929/build/node_modules/connect/index.js:183:5)
> ```

This is my package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.15.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "@expo-google-fonts/lato": "^0.2.0",
    "@expo-google-fonts/quicksand": "^0.2.0",
    "@expo-google-fonts/raleway": "^0.2.0",
    "@expo-google-fonts/roboto": "^0.2.0",
    "@expo-google-fonts/rubik": "^0.2.0",
    "@magic-sdk/react-native": "^4.4.2",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.9",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.11",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^3.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/cameraroll": "^4.0.4",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.3.5",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.10.1",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^6.0.1",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.4.8",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.5",
    "@react-navigation/compat": "^5.3.20",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.7",
    "@sentry/react-native": "4.9.0",
    "@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api": "^1.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-inline-dotenv": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "cipher-base": "^1.0.4",
    "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^2.3.0",
    "events": "^3.3.0",
    "expo": "~47.0.12",
    "expo-app-auth": "~11.1.0",
    "expo-app-loading": "~2.1.1",
    "expo-application": "~5.0.1",
    "expo-asset": "~8.7.0",
    "expo-blur": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.4.1",
    "expo-constants": "~14.0.2",
    "expo-device": "~5.0.0",
    "expo-document-picker": "~11.0.1",
    "expo-file-system": "~15.1.1",
    "expo-font": "~11.0.1",
    "expo-google-app-auth": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-google-sign-in": "~10.1.0",
    "expo-haptics": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~11.0.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.0.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-location": "~15.0.1",
    "expo-media-library": "~15.0.0",
    "expo-modules-core": "~1.0.4 || ~1.1.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.17.0",
    "expo-permissions": "~14.0.0",
    "expo-sharing": "~11.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.17.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "expo-updates": "~0.15.6",
    "fast-html-parser": "^1.0.1",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "html-entities": "^2.3.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "metro-core": "^0.74.0",
    "patch-package": "^6.4.7",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-collapsible": "^2.8.4",
    "react-devtools": "^4.17.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "react-final-form": "^6.5.3",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.14.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-bouncy-checkbox": "^3.0.4",
    "react-native-breadcrumb": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-calendar-picker": "^7.1.2",
    "react-native-code-push": "^7.0.2",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-config": "^1.4.4",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^6.0.4",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-emoji-selector": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-form-validator": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.18.0",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.2.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.8.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.3",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-haptic-feedback": "^1.11.0",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.16.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.36.2",
    "react-native-image-resizer": "^1.4.5",
    "react-native-input-validator": "^1.0.12",
    "react-native-loading-spinner-overlay": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-maps": "1.3.2",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.0",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.5",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.0.5",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
    "react-native-popover-view": "^5.1.5",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.1.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.18.0",
    "react-native-scroll-into-view": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-share": "^7.0.2",
    "react-native-simple-stepper": "^3.0.3",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^4.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-native-super-grid": "^4.1.3",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-uuid": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-native-webview": "11.23.1",
    "react-native-week-month-date-picker": "^0.3.0",
    "react-native-woocommerce-api": "^1.8.8",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.7.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "redux": "^4.1.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "sentry-expo": "~6.0.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.19",
    "string-random": "^0.1.3",
    "util": "^0.12.4",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "uuidv4": "^6.2.13",
    "woocommerce-api": "^1.5.0",
    "wpapi": "^1.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.15.3",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "3.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "27.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "metro": "^0.74.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.16"
  }
```